# Что делать с json в Spring REST?

Tags: java, spring, rest

Начал я изучение спринга без всякой рест-архитектуры. Тогда всё было легко и просто: добавляли атрибуты, с ними же работали на веб-странице... В результате учебный проект я сделал довольно быстро.

Код из контроллера:

> ```
> @GetMapping
> public String getAlbum(@RequestParam(value="albumId", required = false)Long albumId, Model model) {
>     List<AlbumDomain> albums = albumService.getAlbums(albumId);
>     model.addAttribute("albums", albums);
>     return "albums";
> }
> ```

Но теперь я изучаю REST и схожая задача выглядит уже по-новому:

> ```
>  @GetMapping("/store/albums")
>     public CollectionModel<EntityModel<Album>> all() {
>         List<EntityModel<Album>> albums = service.getAllAlbums().stream()
>                 .map(assembler::toModel)
>                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
>
>         return CollectionModel.of(albums,
>                 linkTo(methodOn(AlbumController.class).all()).withSelfRel());
>     }
> ```

В результате я по адресу получаю json, и это вроде бы круто, и все пишут о преимуществах, но что с ним делать-то? Как мне превратить его в визуальную страницу?

Что мне нужно изучить, чтобы это понять? потому что пока что я гуглю туториалы и ничего дельного не нахожу

Comment: Если коротко, то учить javascript и фреймворки для работы с ним на стороне клиента (типа react, angular). Сервер отдает API, а отображением занимается приложение на javascript в браузере, которое с сервером общается по REST API. Вот базовый пример на react https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/, а тут на angular https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-angular-web

Comment: о, спасибо) видел эти фреймворки, но там что-то всё так запутано по сравнению с классикой хтмл+джс которые я использовал с thymeleaf в прошлых учебных проектах. Придётся разбираться) Нечаянно стану фулстеком)